# A way to combine multiple ogg files into one

Tags: c#, ogg, combiners

Could anyone give me an example code or point me in the right direction of how to combine multiple ogg files into one using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SoX - the Swiss Army knife of sound processing. It is a library in C that can be called from C#.

You can find it here: http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG, its very easy to do it, its a console taht you can run with just simple command from a batch file.

Here you can find instructions on how to do it

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Answer (score -1):

You first convert all the files in the wav.

Sequencer.
http://www.image-line.com/downloads/flstudiodownload.html

You merge files into one ogg
FL Studio - Export - ogg

I can offer 
https://sites.google.com/site/cobnut3d/

There are examples for C #
SlimDX.DirectSound.